# Hook before posting via JSON REST API

Tags: hooks, json, rest-api, wp-api

I have been testing out the [JSON REST API](http://wp-api.org/) the past few days with some pretty good results however I have run into a bit of a barrier when making a post.

I need to hook into the post call before the post is made, however I can't for the life of me find any way to do this. It's fairly important that this is possible, otherwise I may well have to come up with my own solution (which isn't ideal!).

The nearest  I have come to being able to do this is by using the following action:

```
add_action('json_prepare_post', 'receive_post_data');
```

However this is called after the post has been made.

Does anyone have any ideas or is it simply not possible? This [gitHub thread](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/324) pretty much says it isn't possible.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`json_prepare_post` should be `rest_prepare_post` or `rest_prepare_{post_type}`

Answer (score 0):

Today I recommend to use `rest_pre_insert_{post type}` (for Posts `rest_pre_insert_post`, for Pages `rest_pre_insert_post`) because it runs exactly before a post is inserted/updated by `wp_insert_post()` function.

For publishing new posts:

```
add_filter( 'rest_pre_insert_post', 'rudr_new_post', 25, 2 );

function rudr_new_post( $post, $request ) {

    if( isset( $post->ID ) ) {
       return $post;
    }

    // creating a new post

    return $post;

}
```

almost the same code but for post updates:

```
add_filter( 'rest_pre_insert_post', 'rudr_update_post', 25, 2 );

function rudr_update_post( $post, $request ) {

    if( ! isset( $post->ID ) ) {
        return $post;
    }

    // updating an existing post with ID = $post->ID

    return $post;

}
```

And don't forget that `$post` here is not a `WP_Post` object. More example here https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/prevent-trashed-posts-updates-rest-api.html